# Automatically Delete Row if Certain Columns Empty?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a database that contains participant contact information for studies: homePhone, altPhone, and email.

We check participants in and out of the database by keeping a log table. Everytime participants are checked back in in bulk, I run it through a Java application that I wrote, which can also update/remove contact information if necessary.

When a participant has 0 out of the 3 pieces of contact information, it is useless to keep them in the database. Rather than implementing a check in my Java program, is there any way to have the database (running on MySQL) to do this automatically? I tried to create a trigger that checks the 3 columns on UPDATE, but I read online that you cannot alter the table the trigger is associated to?

I know that I could just run :

```
DELETE FROM participants WHERE homePhone=0 AND altPhone=0 AND email=''
```

But I want the database to do this automatically. I'm not too much of a database guru, so if anyone has any insight that would be great. Worst case would be implementing the above line of SQL at the end of my Java program.

Comment: Worst case is to put that line in your java yes, best case scenario is to update your Java application with the condition check!

Comment: Why don't you just create a new trigger?

Comment: I tried writing a trigger, but I read somewhere you can't alter the table that the trigger belongs to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put that query on a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) that get called at each INSERT INTO or UPDATE statement .

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL 5.1.6+ you could use the MySql Event Scheduler.

[Using the Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)